# Different styles of the input in the mobile and the desktop browsers

Tags: mobile, desktop

It ispossible to make the size of input be different in the mobile browser of a site than in a the usual (desktop) browser?
Here's the page http://smartplanka.com/kak-postavit-planku/, where the sizes of the input fields are identical both on the mobile and the desktop browsers. On the mobile browser the input fields exceed the form's right boundary.

I'm actually behind from the evolution of CSS and HTML. But I think there must be something for this.

If it can help: the site is on wordpress and the form is the contactforms7 plugin.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the width of the input fields to 100%:

```
width: 100%;
```

That should do it.